# Django annotate raising AttributeError 'object has no attribute'

Tags: django, django-queryset

Hi I'm trying to use django's annotate and I think I'm doing everything ok but I must be missing something because I'm getting an Attribute Error

Here are my models

```
class Operation(models.Model):
    ...

class Message(models.Model):
    operation = models.ForeignKey(Operation)
    sent_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...
```

And here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    ops = Operation.objects.filter(...)
    ops.annotate(last_message=Max('message__sent_on'))
    ops.order_by('-last_message')

    print ops[0].last_message
```

And I'm getting

```
AttributeError at ...
'Operation' object has no attribute 'last_message'
```

Notice that if I change the annotate to `ops.annotate(last_message=Max('whatever'))` I get a `FieldError`, so the previous syntax was right... but why then can't I access the last_message field?

I'm using django 1.6.10

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Queryset methods do not modify the existing queryset in place, they return a new one. So your `annotate` and `ops` calls are in fact not actually doing anything, as they create a new queryset and then it is immediately thrown away.

You need to reassign the result of the calls:

```
ops = Operation.objects.filter(...)
ops = ops.annotate(last_message=Max('message__sent_on'))
ops = ops.order_by('-last_message')
```

or just do it in one go:

```
ops = Operation.objects.filter(
    ...
).annotate(
    last_message=Max('message__sent_on')
).order_by('-last_message')
```